# Алгоритм определения ранга матрицы

Tags: c++, алгоритм, матрицы

Какой алгоритм лучше использовать для нахождения ранга матрицы `n` на `m`? 
В методе окаймляющих миноров, как я понимаю, нужно прописывать каждое увеличение порядка минора, плюс потом увеличится сложность вычисления при определении определителя. Возможно, я ошибаюсь. 
Конечно, после приведения матрицы к ступенчатому виду всё просто. Чтобы привести матрицу к ступенчатому виду, есть всего пять простых преобразований, но когда какое использовать? С разными матрицами можно действовать по-разному.
Подскажите, какой способ лучше для реализации на языке C++?

Comment: а лучше в каком смысле и  для каких матриц? Лучше это может быть и быстрее работает и понятнее и проще закодить и ещё куча всего.

Comment: Для матрицы любой размерности n на m, заполненную целыми числами. Под "лучше" подразумевается тот алгоритм, который проще реализовать.

Comment: Тогда приводите к диагональной, пишется минут за 15, только не забудьте поменять местами строки/столбцы чтобы избежать деления на 0.

Comment: 15 минут? всего есть 6 простых преобразований над матрицей. И когда какие использовать? к каждой матрице же отдельный подход